# How to calculate a conversion goal value for a large sample size?

Tags: google-analytics

**I need to assign a conversion goal value for user actions made on a website.**

I have already processed the data for a sample size of **210** paid invoices. The statistical analysis of the income values can be seen in the results below...

[image]
[image]

**Which parameter should I use as the conversion value and why?**

Please Note:
*I have posted the same question to Mathematics.SE and stackoverflow due to the feedback on similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260823/which-site-should-i-ask-this-math-question-on*